# How to transfer images on modern cameras?

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I have two modern Sony cameras:

- An A7RIII
- An RX100V

Reading through the API 2.4 documentation, both of these cameras should support "Transferring images".

However in the section labeled "Changing camera function to transferring images", the recommended sequence to do this is:

- camera/getStorageInformation
- camera/setCameraFunction

Neither of those functions are ever listed when I query the available API methods on either camera.

As far as I can tell, both cameras are up to date.

The only way I've been able to find so far is to put the camera in "Send to Smartphone" mode, which starts up a UPnP server but this only provides JPEGs so isn't much use to me.

So how do I transfer images on modern cameras? Is there some magic incantation required to enable the APIs that seem to be assumed present?

Comment: Hi there! Did you ever get this working? I’m trying to debug similar issues at the moment, and could use the help of someone who’s had prior experience with the newer models!

Comment: You can't do it on V version. Ask Sony a firmware update https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75260741/sony-camera-dsc-rx100m5-remote-api

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps i can help you:
You have to take care that some server (Sony Device) need a "Start Rec mode" before other api call even you are not "recording".

After a "Start Rec mode" you will see that the available api list will change (polling or callback).

I have a look to a code that i wrote last year for a RX100V

Here is my init sequence (just after wifi connect...):

1) GetVersion

2) StartRecMode

3) (getAvailableLiveviewSize) if you need liveview ...

4) (setLiveviewFrameInfo) if you need liveview ...
...

"Remote Shooting" is the default.

For Contents Transfert you can do :
setCameraFunction("Contents Transfer",.....

or

back to  Remote Shooting :
setCameraFunction("Remote Shooting", ....

Be aware StartRecMode and  setCameraFunction change take some time you need to wait with polling or callback.

====

I have done a new test .
Step by step:

1) 
Wifi connected
Lcd screen is showing "connecting ..." message

GetEvent  return 10 elements in "availableApiList":
"getVersions"
"getMethodTypes"
"getApplicationInfo"
"getAvailableApiList"
"getEvent"
"getSupportedCameraFunction"
"startRecMode"
"stopRecMode"
"getCameraFunction"
"getAvailableCameraFunction"

2)
I do : "GetVersion" and "StartRecMode" api calls
Lcd screen is now showing current view

GetEvent  return 68 element in availableApiList:
"getVersions"
"getMethodTypes"
"getApplicationInfo"
"getAvailableApiList"
"getEvent" 
"getSupportedCameraFunction" 
"actTakePicture"
"stopRecMode"
"startLiveview"
"stopLiveview"
"startLiveviewWithSize"
"setCameraFunction"
"getCameraFunction"
"getAvailableCameraFunction"
...
...
"getLiveviewFrameInfo"

3) i do: setCameraFunction("Contents Transfer",.....) api call
Lcd is now black with a message about transfert...

GetEvent return 10 elements in availableApiList (not the same that in 1):
"getVersions"
"getMethodTypes"
"getApplicationInfo"
"getAvailableApiList"
"getEvent"
"getSupportedCameraFunction"
"setCameraFunction"
"getCameraFunction"
"getAvailableCameraFunction"
"getStorageInformation"

Comment: On the A7RIII, there's no StartRecMode api. On RX100V, setCameraFunction doesn't show as available or work even when I startRecMode.